mysqldump my database on server returns 2
This issue keeps coming back after many solutions I tried. I am trying to mysqldump my database and compress it using gzip using a single command in PHP/Laravel, this is the latest command I tried:
$filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".gz";
$command = "mysqldump -u " . env('DB_USERNAME') . " -p'" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . "' " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  --no-tablespaces -C | gzip > " . public_path("DBbackup\/") . $filename;
$returnVar = NULL;
$output  = NULL;

exec($command, $output, $returnVar);

it return 2 not 0 meaning that the command failed, and the output is nothing.
then I tried to return the command to check if every variable like env(..) is correct and so on but everything was good, so I tried the command myself and it worked and created the .gz file. I don't understand why using PHP it didn't work?

It's most likely a permissions issue. I'd guess that the web server process doesn't have write access to the DBbackup directory.

@AlexHowansky I gave the user all the permissions - I think - with this command
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON laravel1.* TO 'dbadmin'@'localhost';

That's the permissions for the database. You need permissions for the filesystem. The directory where the file gets created needs to be writable to the user running the web server process.

As I said, even when executing the same command that is used in the code but manually, it works

How can this be done?

Does this answer your question? Using a .php file to generate a MySQL dump

You might have permissions for the command, but whatever user is running the script (web server? Something with cron?) may not have write permissions.

actually I am trying to run it in a route for now but yeah, it would run using corn @aynber

If you're running it in a route, then you need to make sure the web user has write/execute permissions on that folder. If you're going to use cron, it would make more sense to schedule it with artisan instead of a route.

The problem with exec() is that it only returns STDOUT, but the error information you want is likely printed to STDERR. The quick fix is to add 2> /path/to/error.txt and check that if exec() returns a non-zero code.

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original question so I have to leave my comments as an answer. There is one thing that is highly likely to be causing the problem you're experiencing.
You can't load environment variables outside of your configuration files in Laravel in some circumstances. I know this is true when your configuration is Cache'd but it may also apply to the environment type you've set in the .env file (IE Production / Local etc).
It's also bad practice to do so as mentioned in this article: You should never use env() outside of your config files
What you can do is create your own configuration file that references these environment variables or use configuration files already in place such as the Database.php configuration file that ships with Laravel.
It's not explicitily mentioned in the Configuration Documentation but it does say this:

All of the variables listed in the .env file will be loaded into the
$_ENV PHP super-global when your application receives a request.
However, you may use the env function to retrieve values from these
variables in your configuration files.

I think the wording hints that you should not reference the env function outside of configuration files. I say this as it says you can use the env function in configuration files, as opposed to anywhere in the application. It may be said explicitly somewhere else in the documentation that you can't do this but I'm trying to find that now.
EDIT: I found an article that explains this available here: env() Gotcha
EDIT 2: Here is where it's mentioned in the official Laravel Docs: Configuration Caching

I know about the env() can cache and everything but this is not the problem, it loads data correctly as if I return the full command during run, it returns the command correctly
